# ruby object expected, got String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, object, tags

I'm trying to create a song with associated tags, but my create method throws an error:

```
Tag(#70267554396440) expected, got String(#70267493763880)
```

My Songs#create:

```
def create
 tags = params[:song][:tag_list].split(", ")
 @song = current_user.songs.create(song_params)
 tags.each do |tag| 
   if Tag.find_by(:name => tag)
       @song.tags << tag
   else 
     @song.tags.create(:name => tag)
   end
 end
 flash[:success] = "You have successfully created a new track!"
 redirect_to @song
end
```

What should I do? The issue seems to be with adding an existing tag to the song.

Answer (score 3):

You could also potentially simplify your code using the find_or_create_by method:

```
@song.tags << Tag.find_or_create_by(:name => tag.name)
```

Check out [this link](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by) for some documentation.

Answer (score -1):

We need to find the the tag, and then set it in a variable to call it.

```
tags.each do |tag_name| 
  if t = Tag.find_by(:name => tag_name)
    @song.tags << t
  else 
    @song.tags.create(:name => tag_name)
  end
end
```